# Weird OpenSSL ts verify issue

Tags: openssl

I have the .tsr response from a signing process in OpenSSL. `openssl ts -reply` works.

`openssl ts -reply -in b1.tsr -text`

```
Using configuration from g:/progs/openssl/ssl/openssl.cnf                                                                     
Status info:                                                                                                                  
Status: Granted.                                                                                                              
Status description: unspecified                                                                                               
Failure info: unspecified                                                                                                     

TST info:                                                                                                                     
Version: 1                                                                                                                    
Policy OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.2.1.1                                                                                            
Hash Algorithm: sha256                                                                                                        
Message data:                                                                                                                 
    0000 - 10 20 96 d8 03 ec ed 6e-03 56 3d d6 d6 a7 14 50   . .....n.V=....P                                                 
    0010 - b0 a7 53 a9 34 4e b9 57-f7 e2 83 13 5e 0d df e0   ..S.4N.W....^...                                                 
Serial number: 0xA7ADC6135D0A39500F7C3B0C41578D8C2CB62B87                                                                     
Time stamp: Jun 22 10:59:44 2019 GMT                                                                                          
Accuracy: unspecified                                                                                                         
Ordering: no                                                                                                                  
Nonce: 0xD4154ECA4E9A0D06                                                                                                     
TSA: DirName:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Time Stamping Signer #1                   
Extensions:
```

`openssl ts -verify` fails.

```
openssl ts -verify -sha256 -digest "102096d803eced6e03563dd6d6a71450b0a753a9344eb957f7e283135e0ddfe0" -in b1.tsr -CAfile comodo.pem
Verification: FAILED
11928:error:2F06D064:time stamp routines:TS_VERIFY_CERT:certificate verify error:.\crypto\ts\ts_rsp_verify.c:264:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

What's this all about local issuer certificate? I can't use -noverify in "ts" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to build a full certificate chain for openssl to verify you do not only need the root certificate (which you have specified using the `-CAfile` switch) but also the certificate which has been used to sign the TSResponse.

From the man page of `ts`:

```
-untrusted cert_file.pem
           Set of additional untrusted certificates in PEM format which may be needed when building the certificate chain for the TSA's signing certificate. This
           file must contain the TSA signing certificate and all intermediate CA certificates unless the response includes them.  (Optional)
```

Answer (score 1):

A verify error "unable to get local issuer cert" means that OpenSSL wasn't able to find in the local truststore either a complete chain's root (or anchor), or an incomplete chain's next link which might or might not be the root/anchor.

As background, since you don't indicate how much you understand certificate-based verification, `ts -verify` consists of basically four parts:

- check the signature on the token body verifies using the public key in the (claimed) signer's certificate, and some other constraints imposed by RFC3161 are met (there must be only one SignerInfo and it must use signedAttrs including ESSCertId). Whether the signer's cert is included in the timestamp response is controlled by a flag in the RFC3161 request; if it is not included, the verifier/relier must have it already or obtain it by other means.
- build a chain (also called path) that links the claimed signer's certificate to at least one trusted CA, represented by a CA cert called a root or anchor cert which is locally defined as trusted, typically by being present in a truststore. The RFC3161 response *may* include the chain cert(s) but is not required to; if not, the verifier/relier must have it/them already or obtain it/them by other means.
- validate the chain by checking that each certificate's signature verifies under the next higher certificate's (i.e. parent's) public key, that each certificate is valid (in force and not expired) as of the signing time, and a number of other fields in each certificate are appropriate for its usage in the chain; see the details in [RFC5280 sec 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6). Validation *should* include checking that each certificate in the chain is not revoked (as of the signing time), but OpenSSL does not do this part by default; there are several options to do several variants of revocation checking, but you didn't use any of them.
- finally, check that the certificate (chain) is appropriate for the purpose here, namely timestamping. For other cases of certificate use like SSL/TLS and S/MIME we usually need to check not only that the certificate was legitimately issued under authority of a trusted CA but that it was issued *to* a specific entity (a website, or mailserver, or person, who was reliably identified). However for timestamping we usually don't care *which* TSA issued the token, only that *some* valid TSA did, so this last check only verifies that ExtendedKeyUsage of the cert/chain includes (the standardized OID for, and thus permits) timeStamping.

Taken together (and only together) these establish that the data we have is in fact a timestamp token issued by a valid TSA, and has not been faked or altered either intentionally or unintentionally, and thus can be trusted.

For OpenSSL commandline, the root/anchor must be in the truststore used, which consists of either the specified `-CAfile` and/or `-CApath` or the default CAfile and/or CApath if they exist, in either case in PEM format; and (although the man page is not very clear) any other chain cert(s) not in the response message must *either* be in the truststore or the file supplied as `-untrusted` (which must be a single file but can contain multiple certs in PEM format). By default only a root cert is (and historically only a root was) accepted as a chain/path anchor, but with the `-partial_chain` option since 1.0.2 a non-root anchor in the truststore is accepted.

The `ts -reply -text` display doesn't show the CMS level and in particular which cert(s) is(are) provided in it. You can see everything with `asn1parse -inform der [-i]` but must decode it by hand. More conveniently, you can extract the CMS SignedData part, aka the signed token, as per [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637771/openssl-verify-rfc-3161-timestampresp-signed-with-self-signed-certificate) and then examine the certs as follows:

```
 openssl ts -reply -in respfile -token_out -out tokenfile
 openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in tokenfile -print_certs 
 # if desired/necessary, feed any or each of the PEM cert block(s) 
 # to openssl x509 -text -noout to get full details
```

I don't have experience with this TSA, but on the principle that a well-known public TSA's cert and chain should be publicly logged, the only logged cert with that subject known to crt.sh (which also is run by Comodo-now-Sectigo) is https://crt.sh/?id=1437463789 which has one known parent `Sectigo RSA Time Stamping CA` https://crt.sh/?id=1437089092 whose issuer is `USERTrust RSA Certification Authority`; that CA has four certs (potential parents) listed at https://crt.sh/?caid=1167 -- one of them Microsoft codesigning, which would normally be used only if the timestamp is for a Microsoft Authenticode code signature, and the three others all reasonable for general use although the only one named Comodo is quite recent (issued only 3 months ago). FWIW the AIA in id=1437089092 points to http://crt.usertrust.com/USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt which serves the cert from the AddTrust root https://crt.sh/?id=4860286 which is the oldest one (issued 2000 and expiring within a year).

Use the cert(s) in the message to determine which additional chain and anchor certs are needed for the root or anchor you wish to use, and compare to what is provided in your `-CAfile` or another file you might use with `-untrusted`.

Comment: NB I had the issue in the question when the issuer and subject were identical when performing the specified way to comparing explained in RFC 5280, but not according to TLS which requires a binary compare of these fields... Of course, if I generate the certificates with the issuer specified by the previous cert in Java it rearranges the order of the DN. Oh, the joys of X.509...